# Why do I get a phase when taking the FFT of a cosine function?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, phase

I didn't add a phase to my cosine function but nonetheless I get a phase. Does anyone know why?

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq
from scipy.fft import fft, fftshift
from skimage.filters import window



k = np.linspace(0,50,2400)
rx = np.array([0.4])
outer = np.outer(rx,k)

y = 0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*outer) 
yy = np.sum(y,axis=0)

f = fftfreq(len(k), np.diff(k)[0])
yf = fft(yy, norm = "forward")

phase = np.angle(yf)
phase[np.abs(yf) < 0.1] = 0
plt.figure(2)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.plot(phase[:k.size//2])
```

Comment: Do you have an integer number of periods of your cosine in your signal?

Answer (score 0):

As Cris suggested you have non-integer number o periods of your cosine.

You have little mistake that causes this. You are using `np.linspace` which adds values both on start and end points provided (in your case 0 and 50). Since cosine period is 0.4, both far left and far right values will have the same phase (that is 0 degree/radians). From perspective of FFT, those points are next to each other -> both have the same phase -> its like two consecutive samples are the same, which does not happen in cosine function -> you get some phase (and some spectral leakage)

Try fixing linspace by removing last sample:

```
k = np.linspace(0,50 - 50/2400,2400)
```

This will make phase go out (there is only some negligible numeric error):
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Why do you have a phase at all in your figure? Shouldn't it be zero?

Comment: @mikanim notice how very small it is, this is [numerical error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_error). Such errors are caused by working with floating points, they are not perfect - but most of the times we can disregard such small errors